# how to get frames from video in parallel using cv2 & multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I've been working with cv2 & multiprocessing in python, and I finally have a working script that does stuff to the individual frames once they are already in an input queue. However, I wanted to speed up getting the frames into the queue in the first place by using multiple cores, so I tried to use the same multiprocessing approach to read each image into the queue. I can't seem to get this to work though, and I'm not sure why. I thought maybe it was because I was trying to write to one queue, so I split those up, but now I'm wondering if it's because I'm trying to read from the same video file at the same time.

Here is what I am hoping to accomplish in pseudocode:

```
for process in range(processCount):
    start a process that does this:
        for frame in range(startFrame,endFrame):
            set next frame to startFrame
            read frame
            add frame to queue
```

Here is my current code. I've tried using pool & separate processes, but for now I'm sticking to separate processes because I'm not sure if the problem is with queue management. If I call getFrame manually, I get the right stuff into the queue, so I think that function by itself works okay.

I'm sure I'm doing something really silly (or really odd). Can someone suggest a solution? It would be great to just have one queue as well... I just had two to try to break down the problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def getFrame(queue, startFrame, endFrame):
    for frame in range(startFrame, endFrame):
        cap.set(1,frame)
        frameNo = int(cap.get(0))
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        queue.put((frameNo,frame))

file = 'video.mov'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
fileLen = int(cap.get(7))

# get cpuCount for processCount
processCount = mp.cpu_count()/3

inQ1 = mp.JoinableQueue()  # not sure if this is right queue type, but I also tried mp.Queue()
inQ2 = mp.JoinableQueue()
qList = [inQ1,inQ2]

# set up bunches
bunches = []
for startFrame in range(0,fileLen,fileLen/processCount):
    endFrame = startFrame + fileLen/processCount
    bunches.append((startFrame,endFrame))

getFrames = []
for i in range(processCount):
    getFrames.append(mp.Process(target=getFrame, args=(qList[i], bunches[i][0],bunches[i][1],)))

for process in getFrames:
    process.start()

results1 = [inQ1.get() for p in range(bunches[0][0],bunches[0][1])]
results2 = [inQ2.get() for p in range(bunches[1][0],bunches[1][1])]

inQ1.close()
inQ2.close()
cap.release()

for process in getFrames:
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I think it's impossible.

Comment: Sorry - I should have included the result. I get the right number of frames, but they all show up as frameNo 0 and frame None.  (Why do you think it's impossible?)

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a mistake in the code : the use of the same `VideoCapture` object across processes. Obviously there's a conflict on the position currently being read in the file.

This being said, when trying to instantiate one VideoCapture per process, my interpreter crashes (tested with `python3.4.2` + `opencv3.0.0-beta`, and `python2.7.6` + `opencv2.4.8`). Here's my try so far if you want to check it / go further.

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing as mp

def getFrame(queue, startFrame, endFrame):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)  # crashes here
    print("opened capture {}".format(mp.current_process()))
    for frame in range(startFrame, endFrame):
        # cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame)  # opencv3            
        cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame)
        # frameNo = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))  # opencv3
        frameNo = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
        ret, f = cap.read()
        if ret:
            print("{} - put ({})".format(mp.current_process(), frameNo))
            queue.put((frameNo, f))
    cap.release()

file = "video.mov"
capture_temp = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
# fileLen = int((capture_temp).get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))  # opencv3
fileLen = int((capture_temp).get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
capture_temp.release()

# get cpuCount for processCount
# processCount = mp.cpu_count() / 3
processCount = 2

inQ1 = mp.JoinableQueue()  # not sure if this is right queue type, but I also tried mp.Queue()
inQ2 = mp.JoinableQueue()
qList = [inQ1, inQ2]

# set up bunches
bunches = []
for startFrame in range(0, fileLen, int(fileLen / processCount)):
    endFrame = startFrame + int(fileLen / processCount)
    bunches.append((startFrame, endFrame))

getFrames = []
for i in range(processCount):
    getFrames.append(mp.Process(target=getFrame, args=(qList[i], bunches[i][0], bunches[i][1])))

for process in getFrames:
    process.start()

results1 = [inQ1.get() for p in range(bunches[0][0], bunches[0][1])]
results2 = [inQ2.get() for p in range(bunches[1][0], bunches[1][1])]

inQ1.close()
inQ2.close()

for process in getFrames:
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
```

Comment: I forgot, I tried to instantiate the two videocapture objects on the main thread, but they didn't seem to read well either (although there was no crash). It seems more logical to instantiate them in their own process, so that's the code I posted.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize that there was a new post to this thread or I would have replied earlier. I wonder if this would work using managers or something that manages shared memory? For right now I've decided to read in & store the images as pickled files and then read the pickled file to save a little bit of time. It doesn't really help for short videos, but it does for longer ones.

Comment: This works for me with OpenCV 3.3.0 and Python 2.7.13. Two cores are at full load and the messages confirm that the frames are read in both processes.