# Python: What's the fastest way to load a video file into memory?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

#### First some background

I am trying to write my own set of tools for video analysis, mainly for detecting render errors like flashing frames and possibly some other stuff in the future.

**The (obvious) goal is to write a script, that is faster and more accurate than me watching the file in real time.**

Using OpenCV, I have something that looks like this:

```
import cv2


vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Video/OpenCV_Testfile.mov", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
width = 1024
height = 576
length = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

for f in range(length):
    blue_values = []
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, f)
    is_read, frame = vid.read()
    if is_read:
        for row in range(height):
            for col in range(width):
                blue_values.append(frame[row][col][0])
    print(blue_values)
vid.release()
```

**This just prints out a list of all blue values of every frame.**
- Just for simplicity *(My actual script compares a few values across each frame and only saves the frame number when all are equal)*

Although this works, it is not a very fast operation. (Nested loops, but most important, the `read()` method has to be called for every frame, which is rather slow.
I tried to use multiprocessing but basically ended up having the same crashes as described here:

[how to get frames from video in parallel using cv2 & multiprocessing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015792/how-to-get-frames-from-video-in-parallel-using-cv2-multiprocessing-in-python)

**I have a 20s long 1024x576@25fps Testfile which performs as follows:**

- mov, ProRes: **15s**
- mp4, h.264:  **30s**  (too slow)

My machine is capable of playing back h.264 in 1920x1080@50fps with mplayer (which uses ffmpeg to decode). So, I should be able to get more out of this. Which leads me to

#### my Question

**How can I decode a video and simply dump all pixel values into a list for further (possibly multithreaded) operations?** Speed is really all that matters. Note: I'm not fixated on OpenCV. Whatever works best.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you reading first 100 frames only from the video

Comment: Ah, I left it at 100 because I didn't want to use length = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) - I should have noted this. Thanks - I'll edit my post.

Comment: Don't compute the length you don't need it to loop through video. Just run a while true loop and use break when is_read is false

Comment: 20fps is the most that you can expect from python. Try c++ if you need more performance.

Comment: True, thanks! I just had it like this in my original code to be able to read the file partially.

Comment: Those nested loops are far from optimal. Something like `blue_values = frame[:,:,0].flatten().tolist()` will do the same thing, without the interpreter overhead.

Comment: More performance would be to use `numpy.array(frame)`

Comment: @ArpitSolanki `frame` already is a numpy array, how would that help?

Comment: If so then loops are not needed they can be used directly anywhere.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! I tried it with my code, but actually got slower performance. (21s vs. 15s with my for loops). Interesting.

Comment: @michaelh Hmm, that is interesting, now I'm somewhat curious as why that is :) It may be useful if you could upload the 2 videos somewhere for others to try. | BTW, can you seek in the video? (by setting `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`) What if you had one VideoCapture per thread, each dealing with only a section of the video?

Comment: Is it possible to upload the video file into memory and the read with cv2.Vidcap?